# Different instances of a web application for different requests

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, web, tomcat7

If a Web application is deployed on a server ( in my case its apache 7) ... And if I try to use different computers to access my web application. It should handle all the requests by itself and create an instance of a web application for each and every different request? Am I right?

Using Dynamic Web Project.

Comment: @Tomasz : You edited... Now give me the answer :p ... And hurry I need to fix this please !!!

Comment: Demanding help isn't going to get you very far, and generally on the internet trying to assert that your urgency should be our urgency actually makes people help _more slowly_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : You are scaring me right now...

Comment: This whole website scares me.

Comment: hehhehee :D ... Thanks guys but now I am in a bigger trouble after asking this question... A wierd way to live ... I just wana cry and bang my head on a wall few times...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. There is just one instance of the web application deployed from a WAR file. Also there will only be a single instance of each servlet.

The only entities that are created per instance<sup>1</sup> are [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) and [`HttpServletResponse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html). IF two computers access the exact same URL at the same time, two instances of aforementioned objects will be created and passed to the same servlet.

<sup>1: Tomcat actually reuses instances of [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) and [`HttpServletResponse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) after the request is processed. But this is probably a microoptimization, irrelevant to the question.</sup>

Comment: SO how will we be able to create different instances for different requests

Comment: @BratRosm: different instances of what? There is just **one** instance of the web application. Different requests can be differentiated because they have different instances of `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` associated. Can you clarify a bit your question?

Comment: Got you :) .. Thanks... Cause I had this confusion.. I read this from a book.. I probably understood the whole thing wrong

Comment: @BratRosm: "*[...]IF two computers access the exact same URL at the same time, two instances of aforementioned objects will be created and passed to the same servlet.[...]*" - two threads invoke the same servlet concurrently with two different instances of `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse`.

Comment: Can you please suggest me any book or some link which can clearify these type of matters???

Comment: @BratRosm: Just google "*java servlets tutorial*" or check out [Head First Servlets and JSP](http://www.amazon.com/Head-First-Servlets-JSP-Certified/dp/0596516681)